# PyQt5 does not work with Scrapy normally

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, scrapy, pyqt5, twisted

I covered the whole stackoverflow, but I did not find a working solution

In front of me is the following task: I need to write an application that will accept the name of the product from the user, parse these goods on Avito, dns, Yandex marketplaces and return to the user the minimum price, the maximum and the average price

So, design looks like this:
[GUI of PyQt5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCNuQ.png)

To do all this, I chose PyQt5 for GUI and Scrapy to parse

At first - my one spyder for dns-shop:

```
class dnsEkbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'dnsEkb'
allowed_domains = ['dns-shop.ru']



def __init__(self, custom_input=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(dnsEkbSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.custom_input = custom_input

def start_requests(self):
    params = {'q': str(self.custom_input)}
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url="https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/", method='GET', formdata=params,
                             callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    for thing in response.xpath('//div[@class="product has-avails"]'):
        item = SberItem()
        item['name'] = thing.xpath('div[@class="product-info"]/div[@class="title"]/a/h3/text()').extract_first()
        item['price'] = thing.xpath('div[@class="product-price"]/div[@class="price"]/div[@class="price_g"]'
                                    '/span/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

Each item is sent to the pipline where I add it to the class attribute

```
class SberPipeline(object):
collection_prices = []

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.collection_prices.append(int(item['price'].replace(' ', '')))

@classmethod
def get_collection_prices(cls):
    return cls.collection_prices

@classmethod
def clear_class_variables(cls):
    del cls.collection_prices[:]
```

Then follows the code of the main application

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import design
import scrapy
from threading import Thread
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from sber.sber.spiders.dns import dnsEkbSpider
from sber.sber.spiders.avito import avitoEkbSpide
from sber.sber.pipelines import SberPipeline

SETTINGS = get_project_settings()


class ReactorThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, custom_input):
        """Инициализация потока"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.custom_input = custom_input

    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        configure_logging()
        runner = CrawlerRunner(SETTINGS)
        runner.crawl(dnsEkbSpider, custom_input=self.custom_input)
        runner.crawl(avitoEkbSpider, custom_input=self.custom_input)
        runner.join()
        d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

        reactor.run()  # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished


class SberApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
        self.parseButton.clicked.connect(self.scrapy_work)

    def scrapy_work(self):
        self.customInputValue = str(self.customInput.text())

        if self.customInputValue:

            thread = ReactorThread(self.customInputValue)
            thread.start()

        #     collection_prices = SberPipeline.get_collection_prices()
        #
        #     self.min_output.setText(str(min(collection_prices)))
        #     self.average_output.setText(str(sum(collection_prices)/len(collection_prices)))
        #     self.max_output.setText(str(max(collection_prices)))
        #     
        #     SberPipeline.clear_class_variables()
        #
        # self.customInput.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':  

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    window = SberApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

So, when I run this code, the application is launched, I enter data and spiders are started, data is extracted, prices are processed using pipline. However, if I want to display everything in the user interface, I can  uncomment the code of scrapy_work completely, but then my application just hangs.

I understand that the problem here is that the twested reactor handling the CrawlerCrunner conflicts with the main stream of PyQt5. I tried to install qt5reactor so that the PyQt5 application worked with this and started on the same reactor. About this is written in the scrapbook documentation of the [commons practic](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html). To be more precise: **Using this class the reactor should be explicitly run after scheduling your spiders. It’s recommended you use CrawlerRunner instead of CrawlerProcess if your application is already using Twisted and you want to run Scrapy in the same reactor.** But it did not work

The other variations I used were: ran reactor.run() after app.exec_()

I can try endlessly, but I need to understand how to properly configure this application so that the user can, as many times as necessary, parse data on the entered product name. Tell me, please, how to solve this problem after all, so that everything will work fine?

Comment: Use [`crochet`](https://crochet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you intend to run the twisted reactor in a thread like you're doing. There many global variables set when running and that might be the reason why things are hanging. `crochet` will manage the reactor for you in a thread it controls.